# Swift: Completion closures with instances that conforms to protocol

Tags: ios, polymorphism, swift

I try to use Swift's **closures** like the completion blocks in ObjC when calling async requests.
This seems to works. I'm using a `protocol` for my model classes and in conjunction with an `Array` I get problems. The relevant code:

```
//ModelProtocol.swift
protocol ModelProtocol {
    // all my models should implement `all`
    class func all(completion: ((models: Array<ModelProtocol>) -> Void) )
}

//Person.swift
// calls the HTTP request and should return all Person-Objects in `completion` 
class func all(completion: ((models: Array<ModelProtocol>) -> Void) )  {

    let request = HTTPRequest()
    request.getAll() { (data:NSArray) in
        var persons:Person[] = //... `data` is the result from the HTTP GET request and will be parsed here - this is ok
        completion(models: persons)
    }
}

//HTTPRequest.swift
func getAll(completion: ((data: NSArray) -> Void) )  {
    //... some setup would be here
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in

        var jsonResponse: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray

        completion(data: jsonResponse)
    }
}

//ViewController.swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // use this whole code here - receive all Persons and show in a tableView or something like this
    Person.all( { (models: Array<ModelProtocol>) in
        println(models) //CRASH here
        })
}
```

When I change the `protocol` definition of function `all` (and so the function `all` in `Person.swift`) to `class func all(completion: ((models: Person[]) -> Void) )` it is working.

But I want to use `Array<ModelProtocol>` to use polymorphismus and only use classes that conforms to `ModelProtocol`, that can be `Person` or `House` or whatever.

I think I'm missing something important or basic here. I hope my problem is clear enough.

**Edit**:

In `ViewController.swift` the execution of the App stops at the `println(models)` statement with the message `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Could you please post the error message of the crash?

Comment: Have you tried `ModelProtocol[]` instead of `Array<ModelProtocol>`?

Comment: `ModelProtocol[]` gives the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will do what you want:

```
protocol ModelProtocol {
    // all my models should implement `all`
    class func all(completion: ((models: Array<Self>) -> Void) )
}

class func all(completion: ((models: Array<Person>) -> Void) )  {

    let request = HTTPRequest()
    request.getAll() { (data:NSArray) in
        var persons:Person[] = //... `data` is the result from the HTTP GET request and will be parsed here - this is ok
        completion(models: persons)
    }
}
```